# C++ How to check if class object has value

Tags: c++, class

Basically I'm doing a project where we have to create a employee management system. I created five classes for the five employees (employeeone class) and five classes for employees which are already in the system (employeeinputone class) but I'm having a hard time with showing the employee list. Basically I'm trying to write a code that checks if the new five employees being inputted in the system has value before being shown.

```
class employeeone {
    char emp_one_firstname[20];
    char emp_one_lastname[20];
    int emp_one_experience, emp_one_age, emp_one_ID;

public:
    void get_empone_details();
    void show_empone_details();
    void deallocate_empone_details();
};
```

```
void employeeone::show_empone_details() {
    cout << "Employee Name: " << emp_one_firstname << " " << emp_one_lastname;
    cout << "\nEmployee Experience: " << emp_one_experience << " years";
    cout << "\nEmployee age: " << emp_one_age << " years old";
    cout << "\nEmployee ID: " << emp_one_ID;
}
```

```
class employeeinputone {
    char emp_input1_firstname[20] = "Maria";
    char emp_input1_lastname[20] = "Johnson";
    int emp_input1_experience = 5;
    int emp_input1_age = 25;
    int emp_input1_ID = 589132032;

public:
    void show_input1_details();
};

void employeeinputone::show_input1_details() {
    cout << "Employee Name: " << emp_input1_firstname << " " << emp_input1_lastname << endl;
    cout << "Employee Experience: " << emp_input1_experience << endl;
    cout << "Employee Age: " << emp_input1_age << endl;
    cout << "Employee ID: " << emp_input1_ID << endl;
}
```

```
 case 4: // show employee list
        {
            cout << " " << endl;
            employeeinputone emp_inputone;
            emp_inputone.show_input1_details();
            cout << " " << endl;

            employeeinputtwo emp_inputtwo;
            emp_inputtwo.show_input2_details();
            cout << " " << endl;

            employeeinputthree emp_inputthree;
            emp_inputthree.show_input3_details();
            cout << " " << endl;

            employeeinputfour emp_inputfour;
            emp_inputfour.show_input4_details();
            cout << " " << endl;

            employeeinputfive emp_inputfive;
            emp_inputfive.show_input5_details();
            cout << " " << endl;
    
        }
        break;
```

First I tried using an if statement to check if emp_one_ID is greater than 0, then the new employee void show_empone_details.

`employeeone emp_one_ID; if (emp_one_ID){ //then basically show the new employees }`

Should I create a method for this? Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: A bit of topic, but in the future, remember that you should probably prefer to use `std::array<char, 20>` (if you want to allocate the memory on the stack) or `std::string` or even `std::vector` instead of `char[20]`

Answer (score 3):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here. Classes are used to capture information that certain types of object have in **common**. So if all your five employee objects have first name, last name, age, ID and experience, then you create **one** class for all five employees. Like this

```
class employee {
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int experience, age, ID;

public:
    void get_details();
    void show_details();
    void deallocate_details();
};
```

When you write your code like this you don't have to duplicate all your code for each employee. One `show_details` method can be used to show the details of each employee.

Imagine that your program was supposed to deal with 100 employees or 10000, or a million? Would you write a million different classes? Clearly that's not reasonable, so you need to fix this fundamental error in your code before you go any further. Probably you should start again, but this time with the correct class declaration.

It also seems from the code you've posted that you don't understand variable scope. Because your 'show employee list' code declares five new variables, then of course those variables are not going to have any values. If your program is meant to handle five employees only, there you should only declare five employee variables in the whole program (presumably at the start of the `main` function). Or better still there should be an array of five employees declared.

```
int main()
{
    employee the_employees[5];
    ...
}
```

That array contains all the employees that your program needs. Then (for example) you would get all the employee details with code like this

```
// get details for all five employees
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     the_employees[i].get_details();
```